# SQL - LIKE command using subquery returning multiple rows

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-like

I am trying to run a subquery with the same table.

Essentially I have the 1st query:

```
SELECT workorder
FROM pidata
WHERE equipment LIKE '%ABC%' and dataofinterest LIKE '%EFG%'
```

And a 2nd query:

```
SELECT workorder
FROM pidata
WHERE dataofinterest LIKE '%HIJ%'
```

I want the 2nd query to be filtered by the results of the 1st query.

My best attempt as doing this is the following:

```
SELECT workorder
FROM pidata
WHERE dataofinterest LIKE '%EFG%' AND workorder LIKE
(SELECT workorder
FROM pidata
WHERE equipment LIKE '%ABC%')
```

but it has resulted in 'single-row subquery returns more than one row' error message.

Comment: There is no question in this post. PS Please do not edit posts in a way that in validates reasonable posted answers.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you get multiple workorders you can do following

```
SELECT workorder
FROM pidata
WHERE dataofinterest LIKE '%EFG%' AND workorder IN
(SELECT workorder
FROM pidata
WHERE equipment LIKE '%ABC%')
```

If the table is very big you can use INNER JOIN

```
SELECT workorder
FROM pidata p1 INNER JOIN   (SELECT workorder
FROM pidata
WHERE equipment LIKE '%ABC%') p2 ON p1.workorder = p2.workorder
WHERE dataofinterest LIKE '%EFG%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without example of data in is not entirely clear, but sound like all you need is to use multiple `like`s in one statement

```sql
SELECT workorder
FROM pidata
WHERE equipment LIKE '%ABC%'
AND dataofinterest LIKE '%EFG%'
AND dataofinterest LIKE '%HIJ%'
```

Comment: I failed to mention in my 1st query I am using the dataofinterest parameter to further filter by. Then in the 2nd query I am looking at a different dataofinterest value. I edited the original post to make it clearer.

Comment: @runjc it is still not very clear, but for updated question a suggest just using like over same column two times. Updated answer.